# Is there some simple example of SCF method?

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm currently learning density functional theory in quantum mechanics, and I learn that given a time independent Schrodinger Equation, we can use SCF method to get the eigenfunction of the Schrodinger equation. But I don't know too much about functional analysis, and I really want some simple example that I can solve it by hand to built some intuition for this method. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The [SCF Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartree%E2%80%93Fock_method) is explained some on this page for those who are unfamiliar with it.

Comment: @Mark Thanks! But what I mean is that is there some really simple examples that I can solve by hand, cause I really want to build some intuitions.

Comment: I understand, this is mostly for other readers of stackexchange who may not be familiar and want to look into it casually.